# macro expand in c++

Tags: c++, macros

Define two macros, as followed:

```
#define MACRO_COMBINE_INNER(A,B) A##B
#define MACRO_COMBINE(A,B) MACRO_COMBINE_INNER(A,B)
```

We use these macros

```
MACRO_COMBINE_INNER(ABC,__LINE__)
MACRO_COMBINE(ABC,__LINE__)
```

If the current line number is 123, that's **LINE** == 123, Why the results expand from the two macros are:

```
ABC__LINE__
ABC123
```

Answer (score 2):

Order of expansion plays role here, first the outlier macro is expanded, then inner ones. In first case, after expanding `MACRO_COMBINE_INNER` you get:

```
  ABC##__LINE__
```

which turns into `ABC__LINE__`, because `__LINE__` is not a separate token here.  In second case, preprocessor expands `MACRO_COMBINE(ABC,__LINE__)`, then 
 `__LINE__` is expanded. `

```
  MACRO_COMBINE_INNER(ABC,123)
```

And then `MACRO_COMBINE_INNER` is expanded

```
  ABC##123
```

There is similar behavior with stringify operator, which requires creating macro like this

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define STRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)
```

To be able use `__LINE__` in string literal:

```
#define THROW_BAD_INDEX(x) throw std::out_of_range \
                           (__FILE__ ":" STRING(__LINE__) ": Bad index")
```

Comment: To be specific about why. This is a well defined behavior by the C++ standard. N4713 states: "Before being substituted, each argument’s preprocessing tokens are completely macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the preprocessing file; no other preprocessing tokens are available." So the macro `__LINE__` have to be evaluated before usable before passing it to the other macro.

Comment: @MaryChang exactly that phrasing makes it somwhat confusing, because  anyone but a mathematician (or not English as first language ) would considered that `__LINE__` should be expanded first before  `ABC##__LINE__` is formed (i.e. before `MACRO_COMBINE_INNER` expanded)

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Don't think that's what Mary was talking about, but wrt your question, right before that phrase, "A parameter in the replacement list, unless preceded by a `#` or `##` preprocessor token or followed by a `##` preprocessor token".  Standardese can indeed be complicated in parts, but "preceded" isn't exactly an obscure term.

Comment: @HWalters that phrase got an ending, that, because of ambiguity of translation to languages like my native, have to be translated from end (bit real logical "end" , some take the end of phrase instead), which inverts meanong of phrase (automated translation even worse). `preceding` and `therein` are words unknown to basic English course. I'm lucky to be familiar with literary language. instead of curtailed version. They really should use less of compound phrases. That semicolon and "no other preprocessing tokens available" is mystery even for me.